# POST to TestUpdateView updates existing object and creates new object

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views, django-testing

I have a test for an UpdateView that is:

- Updating the existing object
- Then trying to create a new blank object at the same time

This behavior does not happen when I run through the view in the browser, so it is something to do with how the test is running.

- POST to the update URL
- Request runs through the UpdateView
- Form_valid() runs and hits `instance.save()`
- Then something is causing a second object to be created right after it saves the original object

Any ideas?

**The Test**

```
class TestReviewUpdateView(TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.review = ReviewFactory()
        self.submission = self.review.submission
        self.factory = RequestFactory()
        self.kwargs = {'submission_pk': self.submission.pk}

    def test_form_valid_with_object(self):
        self.request = self.factory.post(reverse(
            'submissions:review_update', kwargs=self.kwargs))

        # Create user
        self.request.user = StaffFactory()

        view = views.ReviewUpdateView()
        view.request = self.request
        view.object = self.review
        kwargs = {
            'scores': self.review.get_list_of_scores()
        }
        form = forms.ReviewForm(**kwargs)
        form.cleaned_data = {'axe_0': '4', 'axe_1': '4', 'axe_2': '4'}
        response = view.form_valid(form)
        assert response.status_code == 302
```

**The View**

```
class ReviewUpdateView(
    BaseReviewForm,
    UpdateView
):
    """ A view for updating reviews. """

    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.submission = self.get_submission()
        self.conference = self.submission.conference
        return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

def get_submission(self):
    return Submission.upcoming_objects.get_queryset(self.request.user).get(
            pk=self.kwargs['submission_pk'])

    def get_object(self):
        return self.model.objects.get(
            submission=self.submission,
            user=self.request.user)

    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        kwargs = super().get_form_kwargs()
        kwargs.update({
            'scores': self.object.get_list_of_scores(),
        })
        return kwargs

 def save_scores(self, form, instance):
    for field in form.cleaned_data:
        # The score fields will be numbers:
        if "axe_" in field:
            form_field = form.fields[field]
            # Save the field's label as the key and score as value
            instance.scores[form_field.label] = form.cleaned_data[field]
    return instance

    def form_valid(self, form):
        instance = self.get_object()
        instance = self.save_scores(form, instance)
        instance.save()
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

**The Form**

```
class ReviewForm(forms.ModelForm):
    """ Form for new reviews of submissions """
    class Meta:
        model = Review
        fields = []

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        review_fields = kwargs.pop("review_fields")
        scores = kwargs.pop("scores")
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if review_fields:
            for i in review_fields:
                self.fields["axe_%s" % i] = forms.ChoiceField(
                    choices=NUMBER_CHOICES,
                    label=review_fields[i],
                    widget=forms.RadioSelect)
                if scores:
                    self.fields["axe_%s" % i].initial = scores[int(i)]

        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.layout = Layout()
        for i in review_fields:
            self.helper.layout.fields.append(
                InlineRadios("axe_%s" % i)
            )
        self.helper.layout.fields.append(
            ButtonHolder(
                Submit('submit', 'Submit', css_class='btn btn-primary')
            )
```

**The Model**

```
class Review(TimeStampedModel):
    """ Review is a model for collecting answers from reviewers """
    id = models.UUIDField(
        primary_key=True,
        default=uuid.uuid4,
        editable=False,
    )
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        get_user_model(),
        null=False,
        on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    submission = models.ForeignKey(
        Submission,
        null=False,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    scores = JSONField(null=True, blank=True)
    avg_score = models.DecimalField(max_digits=3, decimal_places=2, default=0)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ("user", "submission")
        ordering = ['-avg_score', '-created']

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.avg_score = self.calc_avg_score()
        import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
        # save() is called twice and when it runs a second time, it errors because no values are set
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
        self.submission.save()
```

**Answer**

@dirkgroten pointed me in the right direction. The code solution is the following-

```
def test_form_valid_with_object(self):
    user = User.objects.create_superuser('foo', 'myemail@test.com', 'bar')
    self.review.user = user
    self.review.save()
    self.submission.conference.reviewers.add(user)
    self.client.login(username='foo', password='bar')
    response = self.client.post(
        reverse('submissions:review_update', kwargs=self.kwargs),
        data={'axe_0': '4', 'axe_1': '4', 'axe_2': '4'})
    self.assertEqual(302, response.status_code)
```

Comment: This is not how you should test views: You should just submit a request for that view (`response = self.factory.post(url, data={...})`) and make assertions on the response. Don't try to craft a view object yourself.

Comment: Thank you, that is the feedback I need as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're doing this the wrong way. You should test your form and views in separate tests.

Test your form by instantiating it with `data` and no `instance` for object creation and adding the `instance` for object updates. Check validity of form for valid and invalid input. E.g:

```
form = ReviewForm(data=kwargs, instance=self.submission)
self.assertFalse(form.is_valid())
self.assertTrue(form.errors['some_field'])  # check some_field has an error
```

Then test your views by just making a request to them and testing the response:

```
self.client.force_login(user) # if you test for logged in user
response = self.client.post(url, data={...}) # this runs all your view code
self.assertEqual(302, response.status_code)  # form was valid
self.assertTrue(Review.objects.exists())
# or in case of invalid data
self.assertEqual(200, response.status_code)
self.assertTrue(response.context['form'].errors)
```

Comment: 2 questions - I'm getting `AttributeError: 'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'status_code''` when I try to assert the status_code. I would have expected the response would return a status code? Also where would you pass the `instance` in the request to the `UpdateView`?

Comment: what is `self.factory`? You should use `self.client` if your test cases are subclasses of `TestCase`. Updated above.

Comment: Usually the `UpdateView` has url that contains the id of the object to update (`/reviews/<id>`). So it's in the `url`. It could also be that you post the id via a hidden field in the form, then it's just a key/value in `data`.

Comment: In your case it seems the object to update is coming from `self.get_submission()` in combination with the `request.user` but I don't see that method so I don't know how you get it. But apparently it's not posted nor in the url.

Comment: self.factory = RequestFactory(). And right on the URL. In this case, I'm passing a `foreign key` id to query for the object (a way to limit access to the object). Also adding an update to the question. I have it passing now with a 200 - but it isn't testing the `form_valid`

Comment: Meaning the form isn't valid.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Looking into that now. Also I have added the `get_submission()` method above. That is fine as it does lookup the right `submission object`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194492/discussion-between-emile-and-dirkgroten).

Comment: your still constructing the view. Just self.client.post() instead of building the request object.

Comment: Ah ok got it -I believe I'm on the right track now. Thank you again

Comment: Wanted to show the code example - moved to above and accepted yours. Thank you again